# images position in different browsers, html

Tags: css, html, image, background

I want to put an image in two colours as the background, and then 3 images above that background. This is the code that I made:

```
<div  style="position: fixed; z-index:100" height="5px"><img  src="http://i44.tinypic.com/257g1nl.jpg" border="0" style="position: fixed; width:100%" ></div>

<div  style="position: fixed; z-index:500"><a href="http://www.hopesheffield.org/hope"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/70b4wk.jpg" width="435px" border="0" style="position:fixed; left:1050px;top:120px" ></a></div>

<div style="position: fixed; z-index:500"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/11k84mu.jpg"   border="0" width:"435px" style="position:fixed; left:550px;top:120px"> </div> 

<div style="position: fixed; z-index:500"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2sax8nt.png" border="0" width:"535px" style="position:fixed; left:650px; top:550px"></div> 



<head>{{ head_content }}   

<style type="text/css">
  html {
  overflow:hidden;
  }
 </style>

</head>
```

Also, I don't want scroll. At the momment, it is working on internet explorer, but when I open the page from Safari, the images above the background are shifted. Any idea?

This is the webpage: http://www.hopesheffield.org/

Thanks!!

Comment: First of all go fix your HTML – adding a Doctype declaration is the first step to getting similar results in different browsers (and not relying on their error correction mechanism, which will most likely lead to different outcomes). http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.hopesheffield.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try positioning with relative values for the 'left' property instead of number of pixels.

As in : `left:25%;` and `left:60%;` for your images.

For a more fluid experience on mobile devices as well try not to set a fixed size for images, but rather apply the same relative values in the css not html attributes.

Also you might have to think about using css media queries if your problem persists.

Comment: thanks you, althought I think that the website that you saw was the old version, since the new one had some problems! :)

Comment: Well then you could post a link to the new version and I will try to help :)

Comment: yeah, now the new version is uploaded! :) I think now is working properly in all the browsers, but it looks strange in the iPad, when it is in vertical position, since the bottom image goes down and a white space appears between the other three and this one. thanks!!!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more info that might help you on the iPad problem.

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="cover">
    <img  src="http://i44.tinypic.com/257g1nl.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="right">
<a href="http://www.hopesheffield.org/hope">
    <img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/70b4wk.jpg" width="435px"/></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
<img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/11k84mu.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2sax8nt.png" />
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.cover{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.right{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    right:25%;
    margin-right:-217px;
    top:120px;
}
.left{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    left:25%;
    margin-left:-194px;
    top:120px;
}
.bottom{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-382px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IpKgv)

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was very useful!! The only thing that I had to add was style="position: fixed; width:100%" in the background image tag. Now it looks good in iPad when it is in horizontal position. However, when I put it in vertical, the last image goes down and there is a white space between the images+background and this last image...any suggestion, please?